# Node Redis Client Not Working With Method "HMSET"

Tags: node.js, command, node-redis

I have the following code block that fails:

```
this.redisClient.hmset('user:' + userObj.getUserId(), {
                'userId' : userObj.getUserId(),
                'salutation' : userObj.getSalutation(),
                'fn' : userObj.getFn(),
                'mi' : userObj.getMi(),
                'ln' : userObj.getLn(),
                'suffix' : userObj.getSuffix(),
                'userType' : userObj.getUserType(),
                'created' : userObj.getCreated()
            });
```

The error stack is as follows:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'hmset' of undefined
at /node_apps/oc/api/v1/routes/user/db.user.js:70:34
at try_callback (/node_apps/oc/api/v1/node_modules/redis/index.js:484:9)
at RedisClient.return_reply (/node_apps/oc/api/v1/node_modules/redis/index.js:555:13)
at HiredisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/node_apps/oc/api/v1/node_modules/redis/index.js:256:14)
at HiredisReplyParser.emit (events.js:67:17)
at HiredisReplyParser.execute (/node_apps/oc/api/v1/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/hiredis.js:43:18)
at RedisClient.on_data (/node_apps/oc/api/v1/node_modules/redis/index.js:440:27)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_apps/oc/api/v1/node_modules/redis/index.js:70:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
at TCP.onread (net.js:329:14)
```

I am running Node 0.6.17 with Node Redis client. Any insight? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Node thinks you're calling `hmset` on `undefined`, that means it thinks that `this.redisClient` is undefined; quite often, this is because the value of `this` is not what you think it is (although it could be that `redisClient` wasn't initialized, etc). While it's impossible to say without seeing the surrounding code and how it's called, check to make sure the value of `this` is bound, if necessary.

Comment: Brandon, you're absolutely correct. Although I have setter/getter for my RedisClient, I couldn't access this.redisClient until I added var self = this as the first line in my addUser method. This implementation now yields, self._redisClient.hmset(...); Thanks!